# Setting an UIImageView's frame position relative to parent view in Interface Builder is different when set in code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, xcode4

I have a view controller and a view. I then have a UIImageView created through IB and position using the IB Inspector. Setting the UIImageView's frame to x and y coordinatates to 0 results in the image being placed top left of the view, below the status bar.

If I then implement viewDidLoad method of the view controller and set UIImageView 's frame position using:

```
myimageview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

Which are exactly the same coordinates as defined for the UIImageView in IB, the image is moved up underneath the status bar. It seems the coordiantes when set via code are realtive to the Window and not the parent View as shown IB.

Anyone know why there is a decrepancy between IB and code?

---

**Some useful debugging info:**

*Note: That width and height of the Image View is in fact 35x37. The above dimensions were just to simplify the orignal question.*

The frame info before setting it in code:

```
2011-03-15 13:15:34.249 MyAPP [98288:207] {{0, 49}, {35, 37}}
```

The frame info after setting it in code:

```
2011-03-15 13:15:34.250 MyAPP [98288:207] {{0, 0}, {35, 37}}
```

As defined in Interface Builder:

[image: Interface Builder]

As you can see IB says that the UIImageView  X and Y coordinators are 0 ,0. While the debugging info above says that it's actually 0, 49.

Comment: Is the status bar translucent?

Comment: No, just the default status bar. My application uses the Tab Bar if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem I was having was due to a bug. I've rebuilt the UI in Interface Builder and now it works as expected.

Comment: what is that bug..please help me @Camsoft

Answer (score 4):

I never use the Interface builder, so this answer might be based on some false assumptions, but hopefully my assumtpions are correct.

I assume that before

```
myimageview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

`myimageview.frame` will be set to whatever you set in the interface builder. I would suggest executing the following lines just to see how you're changing the `frame` property:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(myimageview.frame));
myimageview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(myimageview.frame));
```

That should help you figure out the difference.

Btw, the coordinates are always relative to the parent view.

Comment: I've added my debug output in my orignal post.

Answer (score 1):

The frame is relative to the parent object.  So 0,0 will put you at the top left of the parent view.  If that view is your main view then you will be right under the status bar.  If you already have this set in IB why do you need to reposition it?  For what you are doing you may want to use `bounds` instead since it is in the space of the object itself.  I don't use IB much, but it may be that you are setting the bounds.

Comment: Here's some background: I've built the entire UI using IB. I'm then using CABasicAnimation to animate the position of the Image View. I noticed that start position was different when the animation started than what was set in IB. After narrowing it down I noticed that setting the frame in code resulted in the above discrepancy. The issue is that the Image View seems to be using the Window as the parent coordinate system and not that of the real parent View.

Comment: When you are setting the frame is the UIImageView still under the same parent as it was in IB?